# Find the radius of convergence R for power series $\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} n^a z^n$

Tags: convergence-divergence, power-series

For power series $\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} n^a z^n$

The series seems to be diverging as $C>1$. How can I find the radius of convergence R at this instance?

Comment: Cauchy-Hadamard formula would work.

Comment: Ratio test${}$?